# I have a date 22/04/2019, I want to just get 04 which is the month. How can I get that in Javascript using any method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a date field in which the date is in a format of  22/04/2019. I want to pick only the month which is 04 here.

How can I do that? Is there any method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.getMonth()`. The first month starts with 0 so add 1 to get the actual result

```js
var a=new Date('2019,04,22');
console.log(a.getMonth()+1)
```

Comment: Happy to help !